# PHP Oauth inside page TAB

Tags: oauth, tabs, facebook-php-sdk

My tab needs to know the date when a user becomes fan, so i've to ask for permissions. Despite facebook official documentation, i made it successfully and the user is redirected to the oauth dialog and after he confirms, back to the tab.

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user)
{
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    try
    {
        $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/pageid");
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        $user = null;
    }
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
        oauth_url += '?client_id=<?=$app_id?>';
        oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.facebook.com/<?=$pageid?>?sk=app_<?=$app_id?>');
        oauth_url += '&scope='
        window.top.location = oauth_url;
    </script>
    <?
    die();
}
```

All works, but i'm not able to parse the error response in case users don't accept the dialog.
The returning url is:

```
https://www.facebook.com/page?sk=app_appid&error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.#_=_
```

But the iframe inside tab doesn't have any parameters.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only pass data to the iframe on the tab using the `app_data` parameter in the URL. You will have to redirect unsuccessful login attempts to a URL like:

`https://www.facebook.com/{your_page}?v=app_{app_id}&app_data={your_string}`

E.g. `https://www.facebook.com/{your_page}?v=app_{app_id}&app_data=login_failed`

The `login_failed` still will appear in the decoded `signed_request`

Comment: I can't find where define a different redirect url if user click "cancel" instead of "go to app".

Comment: Add the parameter `cancel_url` to your login code:
`cancel_url=https://www.facebook.com/{your_page}?v=app_{app_id}&app_data=login_failed`